# Delete "Deleted" files from local repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

How do I delete files which have been deleted from the Repo but have not been deleted locally yet?

Essentially, I'm writing a **build script** in powershell that needs to get the most up-to-date changes from the repo and checkout, but there might be files which were deleted from the repo which haven't yet been deleted from my local checkout. I mean, one solution is to just delete everything and do a clean checkout, but that's rather expensive and would take a long time. I could also do a svn status and look for anything with a "D" and delete them locally, but that's rather tedious. I'd like to also just overwrite any conflicts and --force the checkout for files which need to be merged.

Is there some simple command like revert or a checkout switch that I'm missing?

---

****Edit: There are actually two different cases that I need to handle:**

**Part A)** In one section, I need to leave anything modified in the working copy alone and just checkout the changes that aren't conflicts or merged. I need this to never abort, meaning that I just want to throw away anything that has a problem and keep the working/local copy.

I was thinking of using: `svn update --accept mine-full --force` (*Note*: This is on the root directory and not individual files)

**Part B)** In the other section, I want to overwrite any changes and delete files which were deleted in the repo.

I was thinking of using: `svn update --accept theirs-full --force` (*Note*: This is on the root directory and not individual files)

Would this work? Or is --force (or --accept) not what I want to be using?

---

My main concern with using update is that it will abort the entire process if there's a problem, won't it? What does --force do with svn update? It also doesn't delete unversioned items.

Revert isn't exactly what I need either, is it? It doesn't delete any of my unversioned items.

Also, doesn't checkout just do the same thing as update if there are already local files? It would be much simpler to just use checkout in the case where nothing exists yet. The problem is that I cannot specify the --accept parameter with svn checkout. I suppose I could test if the folder exists and then do a checkout or an update accordingly.

Comment: does `svn up` not work? It should delete the file(s) for you (but would also update the rest of the working copy as well).

Comment: The command to bring changes from repo to working copy is **update**. If there's a reason that prevents you from using it, you should clearly explain it so we're able to help.

Comment: @crashmstr: I edited my post above. With the two different cases, is svn update still what I want to do? Thanks!

Comment: @Alvaro: I edited my post above. With the two different cases, is svn update still what I want to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Part A, I used:

```
svn update --accept mine-full --force
```

For Part B, I just did:

Step 1:

```
svn revert $localPath
```

Step 2:

```
svn update $localPath
```

Step 3 (using powershell + svn status, but can be done with rm -rf grep/sed in *nix):

```
svn status $localPath --no-ignore |
                Select-String '^[?I]' |
                ForEach-Object {
                    [Regex]::Match($_.Line, '^[^\s]*\s+(.*)$').Groups[1].Value
                } |
                Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the file manually, it will be restored until you update your local repository to the same version that lacks the file in the repository.  So, the first course of action is to attempt to update your repository.

```
svn update
```

There are a few caveats.  First, if someone deleted the file but didn't checkin his deletion, the deletion isn't really in the remote repository.  Second, if you modified the file, you *might* get a conflict, as the deleted file in the repository isn't the same deleted file on your disk.

Assuming that there are some sort of conflicts which does make the update difficult.  You should try

```
svn revert <problem file name>
```

And attempt the update again.

Using the `--force` option without having an excellent picture of what is going on is almost always a bad idea.  Basically it's like not listening to expert advise.  If you have more expertise than the advice giver, you know the caveats and pain points to avoid.  If you don't have more expertise than the advice giver, you are going to hurt yourself.  `--force` is not a "try again, ignoring warnings" flag, it is a "do it anyway, even if it totally screws up things" option.

Comment: Hey, I edited my original post to clarify a bit. However, this is for a build script, so I don't necesasrily care if I cannot recommit everything, as long as the process doesn't abort due to a failed checkout or a merge prompt.

Comment: @Jordan, If this is for an automated build script, it should be checking out the entire source tree "fresh" into a new directory.  If this is for a development environment, then the user should have no issue typing these commands.  If you're doing something in-between, probably better to separate out the two cases.

Comment: @Jordan, I think you misunderstand `svn revert` it reverts you back to the copy of the file(s) you checked out of the repository.  After such a command, there cannot be file conflicts on that file, so your `svn update` will work cleanly for that file.

Comment: It's for a build script, but I don't want to do a fresh checkout, because the source is about 10GB and it would take forever to checkout code that wasn't modified.
Also, sometimes the script gets edited in the working copy for temporary builds+fixes and changes shouldn't be overwritten (part A, not my choice unfortunately).

As for svn revert, yes, but couldn't I just svn update and --accept theirs-full --force or something?

Comment: Also, revert does not remove newly added files. Is there a way to do this without deleting the working copy folder and checking out clean again?

Comment: @Jordan, Revert doesn't update anything.  It reverts you back to what you checked out.  From there an update should work, without conflicts.  With SVN you can't use the common meanings of "revert" and "update", they have technical meanings.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but it also doesn't remove unversioned files which were added after the checkout, which is what I need to do.

Comment: @Jordan, unrevisioned file removal is the domain of the person / system that put the files there.  You can't ask a revision tracking system to mess with files it hasn't been told to mess with.  Insisting subversion "do something about it" while not even following good build practices is a fine example of fixing the problem while ignoring its cases.

Comment: Fair enough, but that was my original question...

Also, in this case, the files which are now "unversioned" would have first been deleted in the repo, meaning that SVN does know about them. You also appear to be twisting/misunderstanding what I was asking. I do agreem, however, that it is better to do a revert + update, but that still leaves me with unversioned files. That's okay though, I figured it out using powershell + svn status. However, you mention that SVN shouldn't deal with unversioned items, but many cients do (such as tortoiseSVN), albeit probably only for convenience. Just no cli

Comment: I'd also like to point out that you can do this in git, meaning that it IS the role of some revision tracking systems to do something similar.